# Combinatorics - How many numbers between 1 and 10000 are not squared or cubed?

Tags: combinatorics, natural-numbers

Simple question.

How many numbers between 1 and 10000 can't be written as $n^2$ or $n^3$ when $n \in \mathbb N$?

I know the way to solve this is with inclusion-exclusion. but for that I need to find the cardinality of these sets:

1) The set of all numbers between 1 to 10000 that can be written as $n^2$

2) The set of all numbers between 1 to 10000 that can be written as $n^3$

3) The set of all numbers between 1 to 10000 that can be written as $n^6$

How do I find out how many elements are in those sets?

Comment: There are $\lfloor\sqrt[k]{N}\rfloor$ perfect $k$-th powers between $1$ and $N$ (inclusive).

Comment: Hint: How many numbers are there in the list $1, 4, 9, 16, 100^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m_2$ be greatest such that $m_2^2 \le 10000$, then there are $m_2$ squares between $1$ and $10000$, because if we list all the squares we have
$$\underbrace{1^2,\ 2^2,\ \dots, (m_2-1)^2,\ m_2^2}_{\le 10000},\ \underbrace{(m_2+1)^2,\ (m_2+2)^2,\ \cdots}_{>10000}$$
Define $m_3$ and $m_6$ similarly, and then apply inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We need to exclude $n$ such that $(n^2\le 10000)+(n^3\le1000)-(n^6\le10000)$

Comment: @OldJohn, sorry I missed the last zero

Comment: Is the correct answer $9962$?

Comment: @OriaGruber: Nope: $10000=100^2$ so each of $1^2, 2^2, \dots, 100^2$ are $\le 10000$, which means that at least $100$ numbers are squares... so the answer can't be greater than $9900$. (And this doesn't account for cubes!)

Comment: @OriaGruber, $$(n^2\le10000\implies n\le100)+(n^3≤1000\implies n\le21.54)−(n^6≤10000\implies n\le 4.64)=100+21-4=117$$